# getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND with Node.js http.request()

Tags: node.js, openbadge

I'm trying to follow the badgekit tutorial here https://github.com/mozilla/badgekit-api/wiki/Using-BadgeKit-API#references

However, the error I'm getting is a node error with my syntax (I think). This is what I have in the file RetrieveBadgeData.js

```
var http = require("http");
var jws = require('jws');

var claimData = {
    header: { typ: 'JWT', alg: 'HS256' },
    payload: {
        key: 'mastersecret',
        exp: Date.now() + (1000 * 60),
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/systems'
    },
    secret: 'mastersecret'
};
var requestOptions = {
    host: 'http://192.168.1.59:8080',
    path: '/systems',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'JWT token="' + jws.sign(claimData) + '"' }
};

var apiRequest = http.request(requestOptions, function (apiResult) {
    apiResult.on('data', function (badgeData) {
        //process badgeData

    });
});
```

If I browse to 192.168.1.59:8080 I get what you're supposed to get back if the node API is running
But, when I run node RetrieveBadgeData.js (executing the code above) I get this error.

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
    at errnoException (dns.js:37:11)
    at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:124:16)
```

Any ideas?

**Edit**
I've also tried this, which gives me the same error

```
var requestOptions = {
    hostname: 'http://192.168.1.59'
    , port: 8080
    , path: '/systems/badgekit/badges'
    , method: 'GET'
    , headers: { 'Authorization': 'JWT token="' + jws.sign(claimData) + '"' }
};
```

Comment: Regarding your edit, it should be `host: '192.168.1.59'` not `hostname: 'http://192.168.1.59'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is how you're specifying the host:

```
host: 'http://192.168.1.59:8080'
```

Use this instead:

```
hostname: '192.168.1.59`,
port: 8080
```

The `http://` is the protocol, not the host.  The error you're getting is that Node.js can't resolve the hostname you provided.  The [Node.js docs](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) also suggest that the usage of `hostname` is preferred over `host`.

Comment: I had actually thought about that and tried it. Switching to this still gives me the same error.
var requestOptions = {
    hostname: 'http://192.168.1.59'
    , port: 8080
    , path: '/systems/badgekit/badges'
    , method: 'GET'
    , headers: { 'Authorization': 'JWT token="' + jws.sign(claimData) + '"' }
};

Comment: I think that was it as it's just hanging there now like it's running. Thanks!